# Embedding Crosswalk without using eclipse, the app is built with python-for-android

Tags: android, python, ant, crosswalk-runtime

I wrapped a Django server with python-for-android and kivy into my android app and use webview to interact with the user. The app currently works flawlessly. Just that I need to support Android 4.1 which is not a chromium webview. So I want to use Crosswalk to replace the default webview.
My current build process use ant on Mac terminal, so no eclipse involved.
I want to know how to embed Crosswalk without using eclipse.
I tried to copy crosswalk jar files into python-for-android/libs folder, it did compile and generate the APK, but the APK crushes every time I open it.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide on their site to a T .. [Crosswalk Android Install](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html#Migrate-using-command-line-tools)

I found the procedure easy to follow and worked as expected, until i tried the WebRTC demo. It didn't work using the standard cordova build/run commands, so instead, I used commands found in their WebRTC demo.
[Crosswalk Example Using Python Build Commands](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/webrtc.html#How-video-calling-works-in-the-application)

```
python make_apk.py --package=org.crosswalkproject.example \
--manifest=xwalk-webrtc/client/manifest.json
```

You'll need to grab the Android source files from their website (supports x86 and arm), and use it to generate your apk files.

There might be a better way to do this, but this should get you going

Comment: thank you for your quick response. However the app in question is not a cordova app but a native app with python wrapper.

Comment: it was worth a shot. I though maybe the make_apk.py file would give you some answers .. i'm a noob when it comes to python tho! .. gl